# Grabbing a word from a character?

Tags: php

I have done my google research. I've tried preg_match, strsub_replace, almost everything.

I honestly can't seem to figure out how to grab a word that is connected to a character.

I have a statuses system on my website. I am trying to figure out how replace a word with something else if it has the character '@' in it.. like on twitter, when you say '@person'.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to just print matches:

```
preg_match_all("/@([0-9a-z]+)/i",$input,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

to replace them:

```
$input = preg_replace('/@([0-9a-z]+)/i','-->\1<--',$input);
```

will replace `@text` with `-->text<--`, as an example.

Comment: Interesting. It displayed all the names that people wrote with '@'.. However, I need to replace all the names found in the statuses.. how would I grab the substr (with 2 arguments) of the results?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Please provide a sample input and an related output.

Comment: Wait a minute. The script you provided worked. I just need the text to be replaced with, for example: <span>Person</span>.. how would this be possible with the method you used?

Comment: @mvds: since you voted my question down , please test you're code with this string see if you get anything replaced: "some text @123asb text"; please revise you're answer .

Comment: @poelinca fixed. Please review your own answer tomorrow.

Comment: @mvds: please test my code now and i will promise i will revise my answer tomorrow if it doesn't handle the string i gaved in my example . ( please see that as a good practice i'm trying to get the right answer to the OP i'm not voting down i'm posting a comment to allow changes to be made , don't care if it's mine or you'res accepted , but i do care if you vote me down , when you should have asked/comented since we both competing on the same answer ) . let's be honest the true reason to vote me down is ...

Comment: @mvds: $input = "sss @@#@@!$!12334ssss some text";

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good if you try to match , if you try to replace here is how i would do it:

```
$string = "some text @person some other text 
 some @pers
 @pess text";
var_dump(preg_replace('/@.*\s/i', '#replacement#', $string));
```

Where "#replacement#" is the string that replaces all words starting with "@" and ending with a space.

---

Edit , to get the code working in all case ( don't replace emails , don't replace whitespaces as pointed by @mvdc , replace words that start with "special characters" , using U as stated by @mvdc ) This should work in desired cases .

```
$string = "some text @person some other text\n
 some @pers\n
 @pess text email@google.com the email should not be replaced ,\n
 @!11@21ss should be replaced , whitespaces not and \\n not";
var_dump(preg_replace('/\s\@.*\s/U', ' #replacement# ', $string));
exit;
```

---

Edit , 4'th revision

```
  $string = "@sasa32@ some text @person some other text@3232##!@ this can pass as an email
 some @pers\n
 @pess text email@google.com the email should not be replaced ,\n
 @!11@21ss should be replaced , whitespaces not and \\n not @poelinca!";
var_dump(preg_replace('/(\s|^|\A)\@.*(\s|\Z|$)/U', ' #replacement# ', $string));
exit;
```

Comment: could you please tell me why you gaved me a -1 ? doesn't the code do what its supposed to do ?

Comment: this will fail because `.*` will match whitespace as well. Either change `.` to `[a-z]` or add the `U` modifier so the `*` won't be greedy. Then, still, matching `@.*\s` is a bad idea since it will not match "some text @person", because "@person" is not followed by whitespace.

Comment: @mvds: and you are shure about what you're sayng ? , here is how i would interpret it ( eaven tough i had 12 shots of jagermaister ): "." will match anything not just a-z , maybe my word starts with a number ... or a "$" character ... ; "*" will match "0 or more +" when you're "+" will match "1 or more +" so it isn't a big difference here , "\s" will stop the match at the first "white space" . if my regex where wrong why does it replace all "@words" inside the string i gaved as an example , please have a test and see it working .

Comment: @mvds:  honestly i am too drunk to get into an argue but the code i entered here is tested and works , and i can tell you that it handles more words that start with @ than you'res

Comment: I believed mvds's point is that it not only will it accept whitespace (which it actually won't because of your \s flag,) but special characters, which are most likely (though it was not stated in the question,) banned from usernames on the website.

Comment: And if you had "Happy birthday @poelinca!", you would not want the ! to be caught on the username.

Comment: @all: 3'rd revision , should cover everithing ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) for helping you figure out expressions. Interpreting your questions your want to find an element that starts with an "@" followed by characters ...

```
<?php

$isMatches =preg_match_all("/^@.+$/", $stringToSearch, $matches);

?>
```

Would match all templates in a string.

Comment: In PHP, regexes are normal strings.

Comment: Yea, I'm in JavaScript mode ;)

Comment: -1 This will match only strings starting with a `@`, followed by anything. Drop the `^` and replace `.` with `[a-z]`.